# Jquery xml parsing read XML once

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

Example from : http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/

***function xmlParser(xml)*** works fine as it is called on success.

I want to write another ***function xmlParser_selective(selection parameters)***

Does this mean i will have to reread xml via *$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "books.xml", dataType: "xml", success: xmlParser});* ?
My objective is to write a function that can parse some selective nodes on request but I dont want to read xml again as I have already done it on document ready.
I cant make to seem it to work.Any ideas ?
**function xmlParser_selective(selection parameters) ??**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "books.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {

    $('#load').fadeOut();

    $(xml).find("Book").each(function () {

        $(".main").append('<div class="book"><div class="title">' + $(this).find("Title").text() + '</div><div class="description">' + $(this).find("Description").text() + '</div><div class="date">Published ' + $(this).find("Date").text() + '</div></div>');
        $(".book").fadeIn(1000);

    });

}

function xmlParser_selective(selection,parameters) {
    $(xml).find("Book").each(function () {
    // this is not working.How do i get to  $(xml) ? that is read on document ready
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load xml again..

```
   var my_xml;
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "books.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data){
          my_xml = data;
        }
    });



function xmlParser_selective(selection,parameters) {
    $(my_xml).find("Book").each(function () {
    // this is not working.How do i get to  $(xml) ? that is read on document ready
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how will this work ?
I dont want to trigger other function on success.
This function will be called by lets say after page is rendered and by a drop down list ?
Do i have to move my function inside success ?

Comment: I see that you have changed some more ..success: function(data){my_xml = data; }
Let me try it